# Reading the xml file with dynamic fields

Tags: java, dynamic, xml-parsing, jaxb, xmlreader

I have a following xml:

```
<Image>
    <ImageUrl>url</ImageUrl>
    <ImageType>type1</ImageType>
</Image>
```

Here Image Url is always going to be there in xml. But ImageType is optional field so I can get the following xml as well:

```
<Image>
    <ImageUrl>url</ImageUrl>
</Image>
```

or something like this

```
<Image>
    <ImageUrl>url</ImageUrl>
    <CountryCode>01</CountryCode>
</Image>
```

Is there is easy way to read the xml such that I can have following:

```
Image {
    String url; 
    Map<String, String> keyValue; // Key can be CountryCode/ImageType
}
```

Or there is some other data structure that can be populate dynamically without depending on the key. Usually I use jaxb for xml read/write. I am wondering if there is some library which can be used for aforementioned use case or may be jaxb as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273615/java-unmarshlling-xml-to-object-which-are-dynamic - Check the second answer. I believe that's what you want to do.

Comment: You could use [data projection](http://xmlbeam.org) instead of data binding. You may even project any element (like "/parent/*") to a value.

Comment: @K139 Thank you for the suggestions. But It won't work in my case as in aforementioned technique. As we must know element/element path that can be processed by xml to be defined in property file. But in my case  I won't be aware of the different elements/element names.